# Breaking a Repeating-Key XOR Cipher

Tags: python, cryptography, base64, xor, hamming-distance

[Challenge #6](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6)

[Challenge File](http://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/6.txt)

In this Cryptopals Challenge that I am currently working on. I have the correct Hamming function and feasible (though possibly incorrect) FindKey and XOR functions.

---

So far, I have this code...

```
import base64

def binary(n):
    return '{0:08b}'.format(n)

def Hamm(s1, s2):
    d = 0
    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 != c2:
            b1 = binary(c1)
            b2 = binary(c2)
            for a, b in zip(b1, b2):
                if a != b:
                    d += 1
    return(d)

def FindKey(b64_s):
    key_dict = {}
    low = 9999
    previous = 0
    for size in range(2, 40):
        ham1 = b64_s[previous : size + 1]
        ham2 = b64_s[size + 1 : size * 2 + 1]
        low = Hamm(ham1, ham2)/size
        key_dict = {low : size}
        previous = size
    return(key_dict[low])

def XOR(byte_string):
    result = ''
    key = max(byte_string, key=byte_string.count) ^ ord('e')\
    for b in byte_string:
        result += chr(b ^ key)
    print(result)

# get base64 file
b64_string = ''
with open("TestFile_Challenge06_CSIS463.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        b64_string = b64_string + str(line)

XOR(base64.b64decode(b64_string))
```

Answer (score 2):

Read what you wrote again:

> it is the number of different bits between two strings

What you are doing in your code is taking the total number of *characters* that are different between the two strings, instead of *bits*.

I modified your code a little to fix that:

```
    def Hamm(s1, s2):
    d = 0
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2):
        c1 = ord(ch1)
        c2 = ord(ch2)
        while c1 or c2:
            b1 = c1 & 1
            b2 = c2 & 1
            d += b1 ^ b2
            c1 >>= 1
            c2 >>= 1
    return d
```

Comment: I updated my problem. Would you mind having a look at it again? @Shakkhar